# merge multiple txt file to csv - add header

Tags: shell, unix

I have multiple txt file, only one column in each and I'm trying to merge them all into one csv. Ideally I want each column to have the name of the file where they come from, and I am stuck at this last part.

text files look like this (2 examples but I got many more):

```
c.Daphnia.txt
geneA
geneB
geneC

c.Drosophila.txt
geneA
geneD
geneE

c.Mouse.txt
geneA
geneV
geneX
```

**Desired output:**
[image]

At the moment im doing this:
`paste -d',' c* > all.csv`
The output looks like this, it got all the columns but no header.

[image]
Could you help me please?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the sample from input files and expected output

Comment: @Amaranta_Remedios - How many text files are there and is this one time task ??

Comment: I got 40 text file that look like that, always only one column each.
The number of rows per file is not necessarily the same every time. Is actually quite variable, but only one column.

Answer (score 0):

```
custom_paste() (
  IFS=$(printf ',') # or IFS=$','
  printf '%s\n' "$*"
  paste -- "$@"
)

custom_paste c* > all.csv
```

Comment: I did add the custom made command to my  .bash_profile like this :
```custom_paste() 
( IFS=$(printf ',') # or IFS=$',' printf '%s\n' "$*" paste -- "$@" 
)```
 however, when I run custom_paste c* > all.csv, the output is empty.

Comment: I just tested the below in my system. You can put this inside a .sh file and just run the script

custom_paste() {
IFS=$(printf ',') # or IFS=$','
printf '%s\n' "$*"
paste -- "$@"
}

custom_paste D* > all.csv

Comment: I did 

```nano custom_paste.sh

#!/bin/bash
custom_paste() 
{ 
IFS=$(printf ',') # or IFS=$',' printf '%s\n' "$*" paste -- "$@" 
} 

custom_paste c* > all.csv ```

```/.custom_paste.sh```
The output is empty still.

Comment: Where is your custom_paste.sh file and all other files ?? it should be in the same directory as c* files are present. If you do that make sure you also name the function as something else as custom_paste starts with c and ur file names start with c too

Comment: It works in the sense I get an output but all the columns are just merged into the first one. And then I get only the header in the next columns

Comment: Can you paste your output here ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208067/discussion-between-rootkonda-and-amaranta-remedios).

Answer (score 0):

In case it can help someone I ended up using python and doing it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_csv('a.txt',names=['a'])
df2=pd.read_csv('b.txt',names=['b'])
df3=pd.read_csv('c.txt',names=['c'])
df4=pd.read_csv('d.txt',names=['d'])
df5=pd.read_csv('e.txt',names=['e'])

result=pd.concat([df1,df2,df3,df4,df5],axis=1)
result.to_csv('mergedfile.csv',index=False)
```